# Shiny&Leaflet: Error Uploading App to Shinyapps with a polygon

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I would like to add a polygon to a leaflet map that is integrated in Shiny.

I have first uploaded a shiny app to shinyapps.io with just the following code:

#### V1:  No polygons

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='x', token='x', secret='x')


#Define leaflet characteristics and schemes

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite, 
options=tileOptions(minZoom=11, maxZoom=18)) %>% 
      setView(-2.959761, 53.404049, 11) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The shiny app is loaded ok on the local as well as uploaded to the global.
When I add a polygon.shp, I can run the app locally on my computer but when I upload it to shinyapps.io, an error is received.

I believe it is something to do with not supplying only the **.shp but not the .dbf, .prj & .shx**

Please can someone provide a solution, so I can upload my app with the polygon, to the shinyapps.io

#### V2:  With Polygons

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)

rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='x', token='x', secret='x')

IMD <- readOGR('./E08000012.shp')
IMD <- spTransform(IMD, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

#Define leaflet characteristics and schemes

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite, 
options=tileOptions(minZoom=11, maxZoom=18)) %>% 
      setView(-2.959761, 53.404049, 11) %>%
  
      addPolygons(data=jan, 
                  fillColor = ~pal(IMD$imd_score),
                  weight = 0.2,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  dashArray = "0.1",
                  fillOpacity = 1)
  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Upload all files (`cpg`, `dbf`, `fix`, `prj`, `shp` and `shx`) and call `readOGR(dsn = path_to_the_files, layer = "name_of_your_shapefile")` without the `.shp`extension.

Comment: ok, so I have applied instead: IMD <- readOGR(dsn="C:/Users/tasta/Desktop/Map", layer="E08000012"), which again works locally BUT I am still receiving the same error when I open it in the apps.io One thing to note is that I only have: shp, dbf, .prj & .shx in my directory. What do you mean by "upload all files"?